# Computer hardware

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have question related SSD. My laptop is HDD, Window 10 . I need to download a IDE which is not working in my laptop and it is continually hanging, when I asked my teacher he said this IDE will work in laptop whose C drive is working in SSD .For internal SSD I have to open laptop or take it to some service center but it is really far and i cannnot do that. So my question is Can I use external SSD for this purpose. Is this possible to transfer C drive to external SSD or Can V drive work in external SSD?

Comment: Please give more details about the IDE you are trying to use. Also, when you say it is continually hanging, it is not clear whether you mean it's crashing or is simply very slow. At any rate, unless the HDD really is very slow or you are working on very large projects it should not sensibly prevent you from running the IDE and in that case the rest of the laptop is probably not up to the task either. That is unless the drive is faulty in which case you should replace it anyway

Comment: My Institute has built their own IDE And by hanging I mean firstly very slow and then freeze. So can I use external SSD for this purpose?

Comment: It depends on hiw the ide us written.  You most likely can - but before you do this you may want to double-check if the HDD is tje issue - maybe use task manager when running it to see where the bottleneck is.  If its memory/swap, using an external SSD likely wont help.

Comment: When I use that IDE it's power usage in task manager shows VERY HIGH

Comment: That's a strange explanation. Software that is fast on SSD may be slow on HDD, but it shouldn't hang. So either it's not HDD's fault or the issue is in fact caused by sloppy coding. Or both.

Comment: So what should I do.. They asked I should have 8 gb RAM and Cdrive in SSD. I have 8 gb RAM So I thought problem is with HDD

Answer (score 0):

You can take any SATA SSD, which is basically all of them, and put them into a USB enclosure.   That USB enclosure can be plugged into ANY USB port.

Clonezilla or one of a hundred alternative will clone all your data to the new drive.

You then go into the BIOS and set the new drive as the boot drive, and you're done.

However, only a USB 3 port is going to offer the best speed.

USB 2.0 port will downgrade the speed to that of a regular hard drive and even a bit worse.

USB 1.1 port will make your like awful and painful.

Your biggest problem is the fact you have an IDE anything.  IDE hasn't been in use in 10+ years.  This speaks volumes about your laptop.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment

Comment: Besides, it's probably easier to (re)install the IDE onto the the external drive instead. Especially in the case of Windows, a clone won't necessarily boot when you change the connection method.

Comment: Constant hangs indicate issues with the drive that will only be worse when trying to access the drive over USB. A data recovery lab will even go as far as converting native USB to SATA if possible. In cases like this, USB is nothing more than an additional layer of trouble.